# Integration of a function in R containing product term

Tags: r, integration

I need to integrate a function in R of the form

```
f<-function(x,a){prod((2-log(a))^x)}
a<-c(0.5,0.7,0.9,1.2)
integrate(f,0,1,a=a)
```

After running the above codes I get the following error.

```
Error in integrate(f, 0, 1, a = a) :
evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
In addition: Warning message:
In (2 - log(a))^x :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Kindly provide a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `integrate` evaluates `f(x,a)` for a vector `x`.

You can do:

```
a <- c(0.5,0.7,0.9,1.2)

g <- function(x, a){
  sapply(x, function(xi){
    prod((2-log(a))^xi)
  })
}

integrate(g, 0, 1, a = a)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Stephen. It has solved my problem.